# Java issue compiling code in command line: Package does not exist...but it does

Tags: java, command-line, package, javac

I'm trying to compile my Java code with this command (OS X Yosemite):

```
javac -cp "../../;./colorCalculator;" Application.java
```

but I get the following errors (among others that are dependent on this):

```
Application.java:4: error: package colorCalculator does not exist
import colorCalculator.Model;
                  ^
Application.java:5: error: package colorCalculator does not exist
import colorCalculator.View;
                  ^
Application.java:6: error: package colorCalculator does not exist
import colorCalculator.Controller;
```

I have added two class paths.
1. The path for a ".jar" that this application is dependent on.
2. The package that Application.java imports from.

The directory structure is as such:

```
├── colorcalculator
│   ├── Application.java
│   └── colorCalculator
│       ├── Controller.java
│       ├── Model.java
│       └── View.java
└── colorcalculator.zip
```

I run the command from the colorcalculator directory, because that's where Application.java and the colorCalculator package are. What am I doing wrong?

Lastly, the code for your reference if you would like it. It is from a professor's website though, so I'm pretty sure it's correct: [code](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/15-200/)

Thanks!

Comment: Change your `./colorCalculator` to just `.`.

Answer (score 1):

The classpath is  meant to include the *root* of the package structure for any appropriate directory. So the compiler is currently looking for `../../colorCalculator/Model.class` or `./colorCalculator/colorCalculator/Model.class` when you actually just want it to look for `./colorCalculator/Model.class`

Additionally, as you're using OS X, you should use : instead of ; as the path separator.

So you should have:

```
javac -cp ../..:. Application.java
```

Note that you haven't actually added a path to a jar file at all - if you've got a jar file in `../..` you actually want

```
javac -cp ../../whatever.jar:. Application.java
```

Comment: Hmm, I have tried these commands (modified to my classes), but they still don't work. 1. I added the quotation marks around the class paths. 2. I specified the jar itself, but am still getting the same original error message.

Comment: @newbie: You shouldn't need the quotes - that's why I removed them. The important change was to use just . rather than ./colorModel. What operating system are you using thoguh? If it's Unix you should use : instead of ; as the path separator.

Comment: I'm using OS X Yosemite

Comment: @newbie: Well that's the other problem then. Will edit my answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Should have put that in my original post!

Comment: Eh, thanks for the effort... but I have decided to retreat back to an IDE, since I got this working in 20 seconds ;) in IDEA

Comment: @newbie: While that's fine for now, it's worth being *able* to compile from the command line as well. I suggest you try the example I've given and get that working, even if you then go back to the IDE.

Comment: I also suggest that you up-vote and accept this answer, since Jon put some effort into helping you out with this...

Answer (score 0):

Classpath includes the root of your package hierarchy. So since you name your package colorCalculator, the root of that path is not './colorCalculator', but is actually just '.'.

So try -cp "../../;."